# Как числа преобразовать в массив?

Tags: javascript

Суть в том, что не могу получить полный массив из чисел. Что только не перебирал для этого, но он заносит только первое значение в массив.

Как решить данную проблему? Пытался преобразовать в строку, но тоже выводит только 1 значение.

```js
function mostNumbers(numbers) {
  var arr = [numbers];
  console.log(arr);
}

console.log(mostNumbers(1, 2, 3));
```

Answer (score 4):

Или так :

```js
function mostNumbers() {
  return Array.from(arguments);
}
console.log(mostNumbers(3, 2, 7));
```

[Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

Answer (score 4):

*ES6*, детка

1.

```js
function mostNumbers() {
  return [...arguments];
}
console.log(mostNumbers(3, 2, 7));
```

---

2.

```js
function mostNumbers(...numbers) {
  return numbers;
}
console.log(mostNumbers(3, 2, 7));
```

---

Проблема данных методов на данном этапе, что нет проверки на тип. Поэтому либо надо доверять тому, что приходит в функцию, либо делать проверку, а это цикл  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Или писать на TypeScript ))

Answer (score 3):

```js
function mostNumbers() {
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    arr.push(arguments[i]);
  }
  return arr;
}
console.log(mostNumbers(1, 2, 3));
```

Comment: Спасибо,теперь стало все понятно))

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что в твоем примере функция всегда принимает только один параметр, сколько бы ты их ни передавал в функцию. Это ты и наблюдаешь.

Почитай про функции с произвольным кол-вом параметров и как получить к ним доступ, например:
https://learn.javascript.ru/arguments-pseudoarray

Т.е. узнаешь кол-во параметров, создаешь массив нужного размера, а потом в цикле заполняешь.

Ну или передавай как параметр сразу массиы целиком,

Comment: Спасибо за совет, потихоньку дохожу уже до этих статей)) Но суть задачи заключалась именно в том, чтобы передавать 1 параметру несколько чисел

Comment: Можно было передать и так:

function xxx(params)
{
    console.log(params);
}

xxx([1,2,3,4,5,6,7]);